# Get threadGroup using thread id or name

Tags: java

Is there a way to get `threadGroup` information by passing/using thread `id` or `name`? Problem is, I can not use `currentThread()` method. I want to get `threadGroup` information of specific threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()) to get a list of all threads. With the keys from that `Map` you can find the thread you want. After that you can simply call [`getThreadGroup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getThreadGroup()) to get the thread group. Check the following example:

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
for (Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : threads.entrySet()) {
    Thread t = entry.getKey();
    ThreadGroup group = t.getThreadGroup();
    System.out.println(t+" with group: "+group);            
}
```

This will generate an output like this:

```
Thread[main,5,main] with group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system] with group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system] with group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system] with group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
```